# Add a title to my submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, submit-button

I have a submit button in a form, and I want to use the HTML title to make a tooltip appear.

I tried `<%= f.submit "update", class: "btn", title: "Wonderful button" %>` but it didn't worked. I have something like :

`An empty button` and `Wonderful button" type="submit" value="update" />`

Do you know how to fix this ?

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<%= f.submit "Wonderful button", class: "btn" %>
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I want. I want to have a button with a "update" name, but when you pass your mouse on it, it shows more information in a tooltip. That's the [HTML `title` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_title.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try with older way:

```
<%= f.submit "update", :class => "btn", :title => "Wonderful button" %>
```